# Enter href parameter from a variable

Tags: php, hyperlink, parameter-passing, href

I have been asked to fix an old set of code.
There is only one area that I cant sort and I just know it must be simple but have tried everyway I can think of.
Simply put -
a php/html search form interrogates an MySql db
The output is simply into  an HTML table

I am seeking simply to place a link in the end of each result row to call another php script to give the detailed description of the item in that row.
That link needs to carry a parameter giving the index of the chosen item.
That item index is displayed with no problems in the row.

So I need to take something like
`<a href=details_page.php>Info</a>`
and make it into  something like
`<a href=details_page.php?$var=99>Info</a>`

but with the value of $var set from the index value  "$id" i have already acquired for that row

`<a href=details_page.php? $var=****>Info</a>`

with ***replaced with $id

I KNOW its trivially simple but i just seem to have a block

Comment: This is simple string concatenation and printing out the string. What"s your current code and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Echo the id:m inside PHP tags:

```
<a href="details_page.php?var=<?php echo $id ?>">Info</a>
```

Remember to surround the `href` value in quotes.